# How are thermometers calibrated?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, metrology

I know this is quite vague, but I was just thinking about it......like obviously now we mass produce things and we don't really think about them. But how was the first thermometer calibrated/how are they calibrated today in a "thermometer factory?"

Comment: Those are two different questions. For the second question, I would suspect that for household thermometers their manufacturing reproducibility is sufficient to not calibrate individual thermometers. High-end temperature measurement equipment is usually calibrated to NIST-traceable (or your national standards lab) standards as a matter of requirement. I have never had a thermocouple measurement system fail calibration.

Comment: Insufficient effort.  Easily answered by internet search.

Comment: I just hate the degree to which people on this SE downvote. Elitarism never helped anyone.

Comment: I'm quite disappointed myself. I'm getting the vibe that this site is for Harvard/Oxford academics who look down on others and not for your every day Joe who wants to discuss and learn and grow :/

Comment: To be fair, the site is billed as being "for active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy" in the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour). That said, there is probably something here worth discussing on [Meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/) regarding what people mean with all the "insufficient effort" remarks we've had lately.

Comment: @sammygerbil Do consider [this comment](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/what-does-everyone-mean-by-insufficient-research-effort#comment32552_8789) from a working metrologist.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : Noted.  I have commented in the Meta link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calibration is pretty easy: take an isothermal environment and measure two events with known physical effects: an ice-water bath and boiling point of water.  Define your thermometer to read those well defined values at these well defined temperatures and, assuming your thermometer has a roughly linear scaling, you have just calibrated your thermometer.

Its more likely today that thermometers are calibrated against other precise thermometers.  Its also true that, for high precision thermometers, or those used to measure extreme temperatures a very different approach will be employed.  Consider this the 'in principle' approach for everyday temperatures.

It's also easy to see where this naive method is imprecise: what is the salt content of the boiling water/ice bath?  What is the atmospheric pressure/ chemical content of the atmosphere?  These variables, and others, can actually have significant effects on calibration.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, I found it really interesting. Have just gone away and researched the ice water bath/ etc. You're spot on.